# PAHO : both `onMessageDelivered` and `onMessageArrived` is getting called

Tags: mqtt, paho

Here is my paho client connection

```
var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(Constants.MQTT_HOST, Number(Constants.MQTT_PORT), Constants.MQTT_CLIENT_ID);
client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
client.onMessageDelivered = onMessageDelivered;
client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect});
```

When i use

```
    var message = new Paho.MQTT.Message(Utils.uintToString(enc));       
    message.destinationName = targetTopicName;
    client.send(message);
```

to send message, both `onMessageDelivered` and `onMessageArrived` is getting called.

Answer (score 1):

Are you subscribing to that same topic, or one using wildcards that would include it (e.g. #)?

If you were then, both onMessageDelivered and onMessage Arrived would be called. If you are not subscribing, then that sounds like a bug which you could raise here: https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.javascript/issues

Comment: what do u mean by `Are you subscribing to that same topic` ?  If i am chatting with same user `u1` then everytime i will subscribe to topic `user/u1` if i want to chat with user u1